# how i can keep modal open after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

My question is different and didn't get any solution.Question is when i click on active modal opens for 1 sec and then page refresh and change status active to inactive.
I want to keep modal open when i click on active then after hitting send from modal page reloads and change status to inactive.

[image]
[image]

My Modal:

```
  <div class="modal fade text-left" id="small" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel19"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="heading-name">Reason</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="receiver" for="to">To: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="message_value" id="message_value">
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn grey btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-target="myModalLabel19"
                            data-toggle="modal">Send
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For Loop:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

          if (response.data[i]['status'] == 1) {
                  operatorStatus = "Active";
                  statusColor = "<button class='btn btn-primary'  onclick='fn_statusUpdate("+response.data[i]['id']+",0);reason("+response.data[i]['id']+")'>Active</button>";
         } else {
               operatorStatus = "Active";
               statusColor = "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='fn_statusUpdate("+response.data[i]['id']+",1)'>Inactive</button>";
               }
    }
```

Function:

```
     function reason(id) {

        $('.receiver').text('To: ' + id);

        $('#message_value').val(id);
        console.log((JSON.stringify(id)));


        $('#small').modal('show');

    }
```

Comment: Have you looked into using ```sessionStorage```, just set a flag once it's been opened, that way on page refresh, you can check if that flag exists in ```sessionStorage```, if it does, then show the modal? Otherwise, leave it hidden? Is that the gist of the logic that you're doing for? Or possibly even ```localStorage```?

Comment: And what's the problem with your current code?

Comment: @JackBashford problem is when i click on active modal opens for 1 sec and then pages refresh. I want to keep modal open.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V  sorry,i didn't get your question.

Comment: Don't submit. Use AJAX

Comment: @izza Have you tried using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)? You can use it to solve part of your problem...

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V no i have'nt tried it. Let me see how can i use it.

Comment: @izza once the user has set the state to active, set something in ```sessionStorage```, then on page load, check to see if that value exists in ```sessionStorage```, if so, set the state to active rather than inactive, it's really that simple, but by all means, read through the MDN documentation, it'll go through everything you need to know in order to make use of ```sessionStorage```.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V can you code for me with your sessionStorage logic?

Comment: @izza I've provided an answer with some pseudo code, and an explanation of what you could do, and the different approaches you may take to solve this problem. I've included a wrapper around ```sessionStorage``` because I've had experienced where you **need** to use ```JSON.parse``` and ```JSON.stringify```, I think that may no longer be an issue with modern browsers however, I've not actually tested that theory.

Comment: You are not posting enough code. Looking at the code it seems you ARE using AJAX, you just need to preventDefault on the submit or change the button to a type=button instead of type=submit

Comment: @mplungjan yes i'm using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **localStorage** to achieve this basically, you don't have full code so I m assuming and and giving you an example:

```
 function reason(id) {

     $('.receiver').text('To: ' + id);

     $('#message_value').val(id);
     console.log((JSON.stringify(id)));

     localStorage.setItem('isModalActive', '1'); // Add is modal active

     $('#small').modal('show');
    }
```

So now you set **isModalActive** **1** to users localStorage than you can check **onload**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('isModalActive') == '1'){
     $('#small').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Than when you closing to modal dont forget to change the value to 0

```
     localStorage.setItem('isModalActive', '0'); // Add is modal not Active
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this code is opening modal on page refresh. I want to open modal when i click 'Active' only and dont open modal when click on inactive. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

### Pseudo Code

Okay, rather than re-writing the code for you, I'm just gonna write some pseudo code for you, simply because I'm not sure about how it all works or how it all ties together, etc...

So, you want to be able to do some stuff and remember the values prior to the page being refreshed, as far as I'm aware. So, I'd do something like this...

**On load**

```
...

if (sessionStorage.getItem('key') != null) {
   // Show modal or set state to active or whatever...
} else {
   // Hide modal and set state to inactive or whatever... 
}
```

**On State Change**

```
....

if (state.active) {
    // Do something...
} else {
    // Do something else...
}
```

### Explanation

I think you get where I'm going with this? If not it's really quite simple, if you have some value stored in session storage, then you can set the state to active and show the modal. I mean I think that's what you're trying to achieve?

Otherwise, just hide it all and set the state to inactive. I mean if you have many modals, then you could store an object into session storage using something like the code I've written below(keep in mind I've not tested this code):

```
const Session = {
    get: key => {
    try {
        JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
    } catch (e) {
        return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }
    },

  set: (key, data) => {
    try {
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (e) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, data);
    }
  }
};
```

So with this, you could just set some object, i.e. `modalStates` in you JavaScript, and then execute some check on load to check the state of each modal? I mean I'm not sure if you'd want to only allow only one modal to be active at any given time or if you'd want multiple to be active and open, etc...

### Edit

Here's a simple demo, it won't work on here if I'm not mistaken, but if you try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tuhvn1km/), I believe it should work without a problem. Again, this is just an example, it's merely here to give you an idea of how to solve your problem.

```js
const dhtml = document.getElementById("demo");
const modal = document.getElementById("mdoal");
const btn = document.getElementById("change");
let state = {};


// Simple on error function.
const log = arg => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(arg);
};

// Simple get state function.
const getState = () => {
  try {
    if (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("demo")) != null) {
      state = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("demo"));
    } else {
      state = {};
    }
  } catch (e) {
    //log(e);
  }
  return state;
};

// Simple set state function.
const setState = () => {
  try {
    state = sessionStorage.setItem("demo", JSON.stringify(state));
  } catch (e) {
    //log(e);
  }
};

// A simple on state change function.
const updateState = () => {
  if (state.active == null) {
    state.active = true;
  } else {
    state.active = !state.active;
  }
  setState();
  log('State changed.');
};

// A simple render function.
const render = () => {
  if (state.active == null || state.active == false) {
    dhtml.textContent = 'Inactive';
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    dhtml.textContent = 'Active';
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  }
};

// A simple click handler for the change button.
const clickHandler = () => {
  updateState();
  getState();
  render();
  // window.location.reload(); // Simulate a http refresh/redirect.
};

// A simple on load function.
const onLoad = () => {
  getState(); // Update the state object.
  render(); // Initial render;
  btn.onclick = clickHandler;
};


onLoad();
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <p>Inactive</p>
</div>

<div id="mdoal" style="display: none">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>

<button id="change">state change</button>
```

Comment: i have no idea how to use this code. I think this is not the solution of my question.

Comment: It's pseudo code, it's just illustrating the basic logical idea... You want to be able to keep a modal open after the page has refreshed yes? ... Then you either use cookies, local storage, session storage or something that implements a similar technology.... It just allows you to access data that was stored at a previous date....

Comment: yes the simple thing is keep the modal open so that i can type something and then send.

Comment: @izza I've included an example in my answer and a link to a JSFiddle, I've commented out some of the code in this answer because of the fact that stack overflow won't work with things such as ```sessionStorage``` or ```window.location.reload();```, but I'm sure you get the idea either way...

Comment: @izza is it starting to make more sense to you now?